# In GDI + generic error occurred

Tags: c#, .net

I save Image but have error In GDI + generic error occurred.
How to get rid of the error?

```
 public void save_all_image(string path_directory)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list_real_foto.Count; i++)
        {
            string format = list_format_file[i].ToLower();
            list_real_foto[i].Save(path_directory + "\\" + i.ToString() + "." + format);//In GDI + generic error occurred
        }
    }
```

Comment: There could be a number of reasons for this - best place to start would be checking you have permissions to write to the output directory and checking whether the image locked by another process.

Comment: How are created the images your try to save?

Answer (score 0):

GDI+ is about as bad as it gets when it comes to error messages. What I would do in your case is to check that you are saving it to a correct path and then make sure that you have permission to save files there.

You should also avoid concatenating strings to build paths, there is a great helper-class available for that in [System.IO.Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) called [Combine()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx). You might also want to consider using [string.Format()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d.aspx) to make the code a bit easer to read.

```
list_real_foto[i].Save(System.IO.Path.Combine(path_directory, string.Format("{0}.{1}", i, format));
```

Comment: What is passed as `path_directory`? And what type is `list_real_foto`?